# How to secure Token-based or Basic Auth REST Web Service API URL from Replay and DOS Attacks?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, authentication, token

Here is the scenario (I didn't come up with it and I have little wiggle room to change it):

1. User logs into a Java-based and vendor supported webapp, hosted on Tomcat. Server is `CompanyFoo.com`.
2. Generate a token and pass it to a URL link on a JSP page called `LogIntoCompanyBar.jsp`. The URL link is `CompanyBar.com/loginpage.php?token={token}`.
3. CompanyBar will pass the token back to CompanyFoo by calling CompanyFoo's REST API.
4. CompanyFoo's REST API will process token and return user data to CompanyBar.
5. CompanyBar will process user data and grant access to the user.

It's basically an SSO solution such that the a user from CompanyFoo (Java-based) seamlessly logs into CompanyBar (PHP-based). This isn't a scenario where the token must be passed with every request to the REST API while the user is logged into CompanyBar's website. The API's only job is to permit SSO into CompanyBar's website and the token becomes effectively useless after that occurs.

Traffic will be encrypted with HTTPS (TLS).

Now, what I have control is over is security, token generation, and the API -- I'm working on the Java side.

I created a one-time randomly generated HMAC token. The salt is randomly generated. I have a DB table which stores the username, date creation of the token, the token, the salt, and the secret. The secret is random, too, since the token is one-time use only and I'm effectively validating the token passed to the API call by comparing it to what's stored in the DB table. If they are the same, then I return the user data to the caller. Unless I'm missing something (which is very possible), I don't see the point of using any actual non-random data for the secret such as the user's password to the Java-based webapp.

The token will be passed to the REST API call via the Authorization HTTP Header.

If you're still with me, here's where I definitely need some direction.

From what I gather, token-based authentication is not designed to secure a server against MITM/3rd party attacks but secure the server from the client. **But what measures can I take to secure the REST API URL from DOS or Replay attacks?**

Let's say the REST API URL is `CompanyFoo.com/rest/companybar/userdata`. Of course, CompanyBar needs to know the REST API URl. But let's say some disgruntled employee or random individual is privy to the URL and has nefarious intentions..

It got me thinking that maybe I can employ both Basic Authentication and Token-based Authentication for the REST API. Basic will take care of authenticating into Tomcat via Tomcat-users.xml, before the API is even called. And the token can be used for authorization. (Keep in mind that the webapp has nothing to do with Tomcat-users.xml. The webapp is provided by a vendor who leverages its own database for user authentication. It generates a Tomcat session and a vendor-specific session for the webapp user.) Double layer of protection. If a person steals the token, he still needs to know the Tomcat username and password to leverage the REST API, and vice-versa.

**But does employing Basic Authentication and Token-based Authentication, simultaneously, secure the REST API against attacks from the client such as Replay or DOS attacks? And if the answer is no, then what are the advantages and disadvantages of employing both authentication methods?**

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this question. You might get better traffic over at the stack exchange security site, though. Did you ever make any progress on this on your own?